# Error: Java:31 cannot find symbol

Tags: java, generics, types

So I get this error while trying to compile my java program

```
./QuickSort.java:31: cannot find Symbol
Symbol : method compareTo(T)
location: class java.lang.Object
      while(x<high && (arrValues[x].compareTo(arrValue))==1){
                                   ^
```

It says the same for line 35.

I created a generic Class QuickSort and in this case the T value is Person. Line 31 and 35 are in the function `divide`

```
class QuickSort<T> extends AbstractSorter { 
private T[] values;
private int dataCount;

QuickSort(){
    System.out.println("INITILAZIED");
}

public void switchValues(T[] arrValues, int index1, int index2){
    T temporary = arrValues[index1];
    arrValues[index1] = arrValues[index2];
    arrValues[index2] = temporary;
}


public void actualSort(T[] arrValues, int low, int high){
    if(low<high){
        int newHigh = divide(arrValues,low,high);
        actualSort(arrValues,low,newHigh);
        actualSort(arrValues,low+1,high);
    }
}

public int divide(T[] arrValues, int low, int high){
    T arrValue = arrValues[low];
    int x = low - 1;
    int y = high +1;

    while(true){
        ++x;
        while(x<high && (arrValues[x].compareTo(arrValue))== 1){
            ++x;
        }
        --y;
        while(y>low && (arrValues[y].compareTo(arrValue)) == -1){
            --y;
        }
        if(x<y){
            switchValues(arrValues,x,y);
        }
        else
            return y;
    }
}       

public void doSort(){ 
    this.actualSort(values, 0, values.length-1);
}

public void sortArray(int orderOfSort, T[] arrayOfValues){
    this.values = arrayOfValues;
    this.doSort();
    System.out.println("IT WORKED");
}
```

And I have the compareTo Method for Person here.

```
    public int compareTo(Person a){ //1 signifies THIS is alphabetically first, 0 signifies equal, -1 signifies Person a is first
    if(this.lastName.compareTo(a.lastName) == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(this.lastName.compareTo(a.lastName) == 0){
        if(this.firstName.compareTo(a.firstName) == 1){
            return 1;
        }
        else if(this.firstName.compareTo(a.firstName) == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Im not sure whats causing this error.
Your help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You should use `<T extends Comparable<T>>` as generic type, since you'd like to call `compareTo`

Comment: Edit: It was suppposed to say .compareTo not .compareTp. Sorry for the Typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your values are of generic type `T`.  Since that type has no bounds, that least common base type is Object, which has no `compareTo()` method.  As mentioned by @exception1 in a comment, you need to set the lower bound for your `T` type to `Comparable<T>`.